# What should I do to fix a Basement sewer drain vent that is in basement and smells everytime toilet is flushed

Tags: plumbing

]Sewer pipe vent that vents into basement, smells everytime a toilet is flushed in house, pipe is for a basement bathroom, what can I do to fix or vent it to outside

Trying to put pics, saying picture is too big

Comment: Ca  you post a photo please

Comment: without any additional info, the only advice is to have the vent pipe extended to go outside.  How?  We have no idea because we don't know anything about your situation. Please add pics and more info regarding the basement, your location in the world, type of foundation, etc.

Comment: Plumbing vents should _not_ terminate inside the structure for this reason (among others). You should extend the vent outside the house. Whether you do it yourself (with some pics, we may be able to guide you) or hire a plumber to do that is up to you.

Comment: Location would also help.  In some countries/locales it's normal to build a vent stack outside, which is a lot easier to retrofit.

Comment: I have tried to add pics, keeps telling me they are too big

Comment: Go to files, pictures and select a pic. Then you can "resize" to a much lower size.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a real vent, or just a floor drain whose trap has gone dry? If the latter, there have been past answers on that topic.

Comment: Toilet sewer drain pipe is about 20 ft from main sewer pipe, under the concrete floor, about half way to the Main sewer pipe there is a bend and what looks like a regular floor drain....it's deffinately a sewer pipe, because if I flush the basement toilet you can see the toilet paper and shit float by when you look in the "drain holes" and smells like shit

Comment: It's deff an air vent for the basement toilet, if I put a rug over it, less water flow to flush toilet, I remove the rug...it flushes better. But they vented the sewer pipe to make it look like a drain in the floor but everytime toilet upstairs or toilet in basement get flushed, it is straight up shit smell in my basement

Answer (score 0):

You either have to have a vent to the outside, or something called Studor vent. The outside vent will surely require a permit and someone who knows what they are doing, as this is advanced stuff to retrofit. A Studor vent might not be allowed in your location.

Comment: A quick google on "Tudor vent" says it is probably a "Studor vent" (post edited to change spelling), also called  an air admittance valve.